# Optimizing product of $L^1$ norms of a function and its second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, numerical-optimization

Let $\eta : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_0^+$ be a function of class $C_0^2$ such that $\eta(t) \geq 1$ for $|t| \leq 1/2$. Here $\mathbb{R}_0^+$ denotes the set of all positive real numbers including zero.

I am wondering what is the smallest possible value that the product $\|\eta\|_1 \|\eta''\|_1$ can be? Here $\|f\|_1 := \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|dx$. Can we find such an $\eta$ so that the product is minimized?

Comment: Are you sure there **is** a smallest value?  An easy argument shows that $0$ is the infimum but obviously it isn't attainable.

Comment: Thanks. Could you kindly show the argument? Even if the minimum can not be attainable, it would be interesting to have an example with a small product.

Comment: Unless I am doing something wrong, the infimum should be positive. There is not enough space here, so I will put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let
\begin{align*}
M_{+}  & =\max\{|\eta^{\prime}(x)|:\,x\geq0\}=|\eta^{\prime}(x_{+})|,\\
M_{-}  & =\max\{|\eta^{\prime}(x)|:\,x\leq0\}=|\eta^{\prime}(x_{-})|.
\end{align*}
Since $\eta$ has compact support, there exist $x_{1}<x_{-}$ and $x_{2}>x_{+}$
such that $\eta^{\prime}(x_{1})=\eta^{\prime}(x_{2})=0$. By the fundamental
theorem of calculus,
\begin{align*}
M_{+}  & =|\eta^{\prime}(x_{+})|=|\eta^{\prime}(x_{+})-\eta^{\prime}%
(x_{2})|\leq\int_{x_{+}}^{x_{2}}|\eta^{\prime\prime}(t)|\,dt,\\
M_{-}  & =|\eta^{\prime}(x_{-})|=|\eta^{\prime}(x_{-})-\eta^{\prime}%
(x_{1})|\leq\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{-}}|\eta^{\prime\prime}(t)|\,dt,
\end{align*}
which shows that
$$
M_{+}+M_{-}\leq\Vert\eta^{\prime\prime}\Vert_{L^{1}}.
$$
Since $\eta(0)\geq1$ and $\eta$ has compact support, there exists a first time
$x_{3}>0$ such that $\eta(x_{3})=\frac{1}{2}$ and so by the fundamental
theorem of calculus,
$$
\frac{1}{2}\leq\eta(0)-\eta(x_{3})\leq\int_{0}^{x_{3}}|\eta^{\prime
}(t)|\,dt\leq M_{+}(x_{3}-0),
$$
which implies that $x_{3}\geq\frac{1}{2M_{+}}$. But then
$$
\int_{0}^{x_{3}}\eta(t)\,dt\geq\frac{1}{2}x_{3}\geq\frac{1}{4M_{+}}.
$$
Similarly on the negative side$$
\int_{x_{4}}^{0}\eta(t)\,dt\geq\frac{1}{4M_{-}},
$$
where $x_{4}<0$ is the last negative time such that $\eta$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.
This shows that$$
\frac{1}{4M_{+}}+\frac{1}{4M_{-}}_{-}\leq\Vert\eta\Vert_{L^{1}}.
$$
Hence,$$
\Vert\eta\Vert_{L^{1}}\Vert\eta^{\prime\prime}\Vert_{L^{1}}\geq(M_{+}%
+M_{-})\left(  \frac{1}{4M_{+}}+\frac{1}{4M_{-}}\right)  \geq\frac{1}{2}.
$$
These computations are not sharp, but they show that the infimum is positive.